# Minimum of a three variable function

Tags: linear-algebra

I know to find minimum and maximum of a function $f(x)$ using derivatives.
But, is there a systematic approach for finding maximum and minimum of functions with  more number of variables.

Say, what is the minimum of $(x^2+y^2+z^2)$. In this case, it is easy to get $(0,0,0)$.

But, if the question is to find minimum of $(x^2+y^2+z^2)/xyz$, then how we could solve this using a standard approach like we do in the case of single variable functions?

Source: I got this problem accidentally from wolframalpha while looking for some thing different. But wolframalpha solves many such problems and I am curious to know the principle involved in solving such problems.

Comment: Note that to be precise, in the first example the minimum is $0$ and this occurs at $(0,0,0)$.

Comment: Also try to exploit the symmetry of the function, i.e. if you can prove that a minimum can only occur when $x=y=z$, then you can reduce the problem to a single-variable one.

Comment: Thanks @Marconius, it's helpful. I will try to see such a possibility also now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function has $3$ variables. The generalization of the one variable method requires $3$ partial derivatives. This will result in a system of equations.

We have

$$f(x,yz)=\frac{x^2+y^2+z^2}{xyz}.$$

The three equations are

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x }=\frac{2x^2yz-yz(x^2+y^2+z^2)}{(xyz)^2}=0,$$
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y }=\frac{2xy^2z-xz(x^2+y^2+z^2)}{(xyz)^2}=0,$$
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial z }=\frac{2xyz^2-xy(x^2+y^2+z^2)}{(xyz)^2}=0.$$

After some simplification we get

$$2x^2yz=yz(x^2+y^2+z^2),$$
$$2xy^2z=xz(x^2+y^2+z^2),$$
$$2xyz^2=xy(x^2+y^2+z^2).$$

To solve such a system of equations may not be easy.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. I am clear with the method now.

Comment: how to check whether it is a maxima or minima using the generalization?

Comment: he elementary method is to take a straight line through the extremum looking points and check how the function behaves in the neighborhood. There is a theory about checking the nature of a multivariate function in the neighborhood of points: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hessian_matrix.

Answer (score 1):

It often helps to try to simplify the problem first.And see if you can prove or disprove that a minimum exists, before getting into details. For $f=(x^2+y^2+z^2)/xyz$ then we cannot have $x=y=z=0$ and we cannot have $f=0$. But if $x=y=z\not=0$ then $f=3/x$ which can be any non-zero value.Even if we restrict $x,y,z$ to non-negative values, $f$ takes all positive values, but never $0$.